# How to get the current change list of a file in Perforce

Tags: java, perforce

I'm working in java application with perforce.
As you know, perforce handle file with change list. So I want to get the current change list of a file in perforce by java. How can i do that with perforce java lib.

Example.

```
.../frameworks/av/media/libstagefright/MPEG4Extractor.cpp#1 ==> CL: 123456
.../frameworks/av/media/libstagefright/MPEG4Extractor.cpp#2 ==> CL: 135798
.../frameworks/av/media/libstagefright/MPEG4Extractor.cpp#3 ==> CL: 123654
```

==> I know the current version using is #2 ==> So how can i get the returned change list value of MPEG4Extractor.cpp file (the value is 135798).

Thank in advanced

Answer (score 0):

It's always easiest to start by looking at this in the command line.

So: `p4 fstat frameworks/av/media/libstagefright/MPEG4Extractor.cpp#2`

It will print a number of pieces of information about revision 2 of that file. In particular, you want the 'headChange' field.

If you are automating this, or if you ONLY want the headChange field, do:

`p4 -F "%headChange%" fstat frameworks/av/media/libstagefright/MPEG4Extractor.cpp#2`

After you've practiced using this from the command line, you should find it straightforward to use P4Java to do this:

1. Create a `FileSpec` describing the file you care about
2. Call `getExtendedFiles` on your server for that filespec
3. Call `getHeadChange` on the `ExtendedFileSpec` that you get back from the server.